# What tech stack was used to write Windows native applications like File Explorer?

Tags: windows

I'm looking to write a Windows Explorer alternative application, such as [FreeCommander](https://freecommander.com/en/screenshots/).

What underlying language and tech-stack does Microsoft use to create native desktop applications for Windows, such as Windows File Explorer, Control Panel, Calculator, and so on?

[Google search results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+create+a+native+windows+10+desktop+application) point me towards one of `UWP`, `WPF`, `WinForms`, `Java FX + Swing`, `Electron`, `Qt`.

Given the following requirements:

- the app should be as quick and responsive as the native File Explorer
  in reading file metadata and opening files
- the app should support file
  previewing, and file operations -- renaming,
  cutting/copying/pasting/moving etc.
- the app needs to work on Win 10 at
  the least, and support for previous Win version will be nice-to-have
- the app should have the same right-click context menu items for files and
  folders as the default File Explorer
- the app should be mappable to a Windows hot key combo, such as <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
- the app should be installable from a standard installer and not Microsoft Store

What should be my weapon of choice?

Comment: Language and framework doesn't matter. You can write a sluggish monster in any stack.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: But what really was used to write Windows Explorer? C? C++? How do I replicate the effort?

Comment: Applications that come with Windows probably use the Windows API, which was built for C. That would be a good place to start.

Comment: From what I hear, windows is mostly c++. And windows explorer is a crazy complicated piece of software. Thousands of man-years of work. You don't want to replicate it. :)

Comment: "such as Windows File Explorer, Control Panel, Calculator, and so on" - Windows Calculator is open-source, btw. https://github.com/microsoft/calculator This should answer all of your questions, I think :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Excellent! So, as the page says, 'The Windows Calculator app is a modern Windows app written in C++ that ships pre-installed with Windows.'. I will look into the source.

Comment: @SNag RE "I don't want a sluggish monster" - the reverse is true as well, You can write a fast lean app even with Electron. Example: VS Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> such as Windows File Explorer, Control Panel, Calculator, and so on

Windows Calculator is [open-source](https://github.com/microsoft/calculator), BTW.  This should answer all of your questions. See for yourself. :)